# Autoref a single appendix as "Appendix" without \section

Tags: hyperref, appendices, appendix, autoref, aastex

I'm trying to autoref a single appendix as the word "Appendix." It seems simple enough to do with more than one section within the appendix (through use of `\section`), but seems to break when there's only one appendix. I'm using [AASTeX v6.2](https://journals.aas.org/aastex-v6-2-author-guide/). Here's a MWE of my attempt:

```
\documentclass[preprint2]{aastex62}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\Appendixautorefname}{Appendix}

\begin{document}

\title{Appendix Tester}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Testing}
Autoref intro: \autoref{sec:intro}

Autoref appendix: \autoref{app}

\appendix
\label{app}
Appendix text

\end{document}
```

which produces
[image: Current attempt]

My goal is to have it read in Section 2:

> Autoref intro: section 1
> Autoref appendix: Appendix

where Appendix links to the appendix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issuing `\appendix` under [`aastex62`](https://journals.aas.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/aastex62.cls) doesn't set anything except the heading `APPENDIX`, but that heading has no hyperlink handle. It merely sets up the appendix for sections that are similar to what you'd normally use. So, if you just want to hyperlink to the no-section appendix, I'd suggest using a manual naming reference via `\hyperref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint2]{aastex62}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Appendix Tester}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Testing}
Autoref intro: \autoref{sec:intro}

Autoref appendix: \hyperref[app]{Appendix}

\phantomsection
\appendix
\label{app}
Appendix text

\end{document}
```

Note the required use of `\phantomsection` to ensure proper linkage.